# Se deben utilizar metodos obsoletos en Java?

Tags: java

En algunos casos he utilizado métodos que son marcados como obsoletos, sin embargo todo funciona correctamente, pero no se si eso pueda afectar la ejecución del código con el paso del tiempo debido a las actualizaciones de Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no deberías usarlos. Si un método es marcado como obsoleto, significa que en alguna versión futura de Java tal vez sea removido aquel método, y tu programa ya no funcionará.

El que un método sea marcado como obsoleto sirve para darte tiempo de antemano para ir cambiando tu código de una vez en preparación para el día en que el método ya no exista.

La documentación para la anotación [@Deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) agrega algunos razones adicionales para no usarlos:

> Un elemento de un programa anotado con `@Deprecated` es uno que los programadores deberían evitar usar, típicamente porque es peligroso, o porque existe una mejor alternativa.

Answer (score 2):

No deberías de usar métodos obsoletos ya que, que un método se considere obsoleto en nuevas versiones, indica que en algún momento puede dejar de funcionar ya que no va a tener más soporte o incluso puede que sea eliminado (y seguramente será lo que pase) en futuras versiones.

Tienes que intentar utilizar siempre los métodos que están en uso, ya que un método obsoleto es sinónimo de método en desuso. Si necesitases que un programa en concreto pudiera soportar algún método obsoleto podrías hacer una función para que pudiera funcionar tanto con versiones antiguas de Java como con las nuevas, aunque en un futuro deberías de obligar a actualizar la versión de Java a la última.